# kswapd0 slows down the system a lot

Tags: 18.04, kernel, lubuntu, swap

I feel like it started recently (last 3 months). I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Dell XPS i7 with 16 GB RAM.

```
Linux 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         12G        1,0G        991M        1,4G        1,0G
Swap:           19G        1,8G         18G
```

Where there any big changes to kernel/swap behaviour in last few months? Is there anything i can change or test some other settings?

(I need 20 GB of swap, as sometimes I run Docker with many containers.)